# compiler prune loop excution and time costing？

Tags: c++, loops

I am currently trying to play around openmp with dummy loop samples. I found it strange that the compiler probably prune some of the codes and the time costing result is not as expect. this is true even I don't import any openmp things.

My test is simple. dummy loops and see how long did it take.

```
    float duration;
clock_t start=clock();

long lasting=9999999;
long iter1;
long sum=0;
for(iter1=1;iter1<lasting;iter1++)
{
    sum=iter1*10;
}

clock_t finish=clock();

//cout<<sum<<endl;

duration = (float)(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf( "%f seconds\n", duration );
```

this takes 0.0000 seconds, and I think codes inside the loop is not executed. As long as I uncomment `cout<<sum<<endl;` , it shows 0.006 seconds.

Did the compiler prune the codes and things not needed/useful for the output is not executed? I run this program with visual studio 2010 with standard project settings.

Comment: It looks like the compiler optimized out that variable because it is not used, then optimized the loop because it contained no code. Take a look at the optimization flags that are set in the project settings. Also +1 for `long lasting`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it does! While you are running tests this is crucial that you make sure you actually use the data that you produce in your loops. This is called [dead code elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination), one of the most well-known compiler optimizations.

Also, be aware that your loop can be trivially parallelized as it does not have any data dependencies whatsoever. Your compiler is also capable of parallelizing loops(along with many other loop optimizations like unrolling) like this, and even more complex ones. You need to use necessary compiler flags that controls automatic optimizations if you want to measure "pure" performance.

Comment: +1: It's also a good idea to avoid undefined behaviour, such as signed integer overflow, because if the compiler detects that such an overflow is unavoidable, it can what it likes.

Comment: thanks a lot, after turning off those optimizations, I think I am getting "pure" performance.